# Textarea copy with formatting

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I want a textarea in my page to get copied with formatting when copying from other webpages.
When I use TinyMCE or CkEditor it showing the toolbar nearby.
I don't want to show any text editor toolbar near the textarea. It should look like textarea but with formatting while pasting.
Suggest me some ideas.

Comment: Textareas don't support formatting. tinyMCE and CkEditor work by replacing textareas with their own complex set of elements and JavaScript routines to provide formatting.

Comment: If you want textareas with formatting, you'll have to use one of the editors you mentioned, or an alternative, or create your own (this last option would take a long time).

Answer (score 2):

You may use a `div` with `contenteditable="true"`. In the following example you’ll find a `div` first and a `textarea` next, separated by a `button`. If you paste something into the `div` and click the `button`, you’ll see the HTML of the pasted content inside the `textarea`. Of course, you may hide this `textarea` with CSS (`display:none;`) and then use it as a part of an HTML form. The usual practice is to copy the content of the `div` to the `textarea` while submitting the form – e.g. the function applied to the click of the `button` may also a contain a line like `document.myForm.submit();`.

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
#myDiv, #myTxt{
    width:300px;
    height:180px;
    border:1px solid black;
}
#myDiv{
    overflow:auto;
}
#myBtn{
    display:block;
    margin:6px 0px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="myDiv" contenteditable="true"></div>
<button type="button" id="myBtn">See HTML Below</button>
<textarea id="myTxt" readonly></textarea>
<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById("myBtn").onclick = function(){
    document.getElementById("myTxt").innerHTML = document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML;
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/gY8U3/)

Comment: I dont want this. I want to copy paste with formatting in textarea.

Comment: textarea doesn't support formattng, you should emulate textarea by contenteditable="true" inside div

Answer (score 1):

I don't have the points to comment so I'll post this here:

Could you just delete or hide the toolbar of the editor you want to use (with JavaScript) so it looks like a textarea?

You could use something like jQuery's $("TOOLBAR_ID").hide().

Comment: Yes. I want to hide the toolbar of the editor. Or Provide me some other solutions for textarea with formatting